# How do I get the unix timestamp of 6pm/7pm/8pm of the present day in php?

Tags: php, time

How do you, in PHP, get the UNIX timestamp of every hour (on the hour [i.e. 6:00, 7:00, 8:00]) from 6am to 9pm of the present day?

Comment: use `strtotime()` or `mktime()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for ($i=6; $i<=21; $i++)
    echo strtotime("$i:00") . '\n';
```